# Angular / Firebase: Convert Material Date Picker Date from undefined into a time stamp

Tags: angular, date, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material

**What I'm Using**

- angular
- firebase

**What I have**

- A selection of inputs
- A Material Date Picker
- When I hit a button, the values from the inputs are written to firebase

**What isn't working**

- When selecting a date from the material date picker, it's returned as undefined

**What I'd like to achieve**

- I'd like to be able to take the selected date from the material date picker and update a firebase node along with the rest of my data
- I would like to save the selected date as a timestamp in firebase
- When reading data back, I would like to read the timestamp in a reasonable format (suggestions most welcome here)

**Questions**

1. Why is the date returning as undefined?
2. Once question #1 is sorted, how can i convert the date into a timestamp
3. When it comes to reading the data (after it has been added to firebase), how can I convert a timestamp to an actual readable date?

**My Add New Data Component HTML**

```html
<!-- LIST OF DATA INPUTS -->
<li>
  <div class="label"> Reference </div>
  <div class="data"> 
    <input #newReference type='text' placeholder='reference' /> 
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="label"> Date </div>
  <div class="data"> 
    <material-datepicker #newDate></material-datepicker>
  </div>
</li>

<!-- ADD DATA BUTTON -->
<button (click)="addDATA(newReference.value, newDate.value)"> 
  Add 
</button>
```

**My Data Service that writes data to firebase**

- I have a service which successfully writes a multi-path / atomic update to firebase
- The only reason it fails (unless I comment it out..) is the date

```ts
addDATA(reference: string, date: string) {

  // Data to be added
  var dataToAdd = {
    project_date: date,
    project_reference: reference
  }

  // Group the updates to the associated firebase nodes
  var updates = {};
  updates['/my_list'] = dataToAdd;


  // Make an update to the realtime database
  this.saveToRealtimeDatabase(updates);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: **What isn't working**

When selecting a date from the material date picker, it's returned as undefined

**Answer:**

You cannot save date in the firebase database as date objects because it only accepts strings. Convert the date object to string.
Not sure if Angular has method like [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) but if it does, use it.

Comment: You can just use the native `Date` methods.

Comment: Hi both. I'm new to this. Any answers that include code would help me massively. (And would obviously be appreciated! :))

Comment: try Googling how to convert date objects to strings in Angular